# How to build an overfitted network in order to increase performances

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, overfitting, regularization

I am learning how to implement CNN, and searching on the internet I have found that a trick to design a good network is to first build it in such a way that it overfits, and then use regularization to elimnate overfitting and have a good performing network.

But how do I do this? I don't understand how do I build a network that overfits on purpose? And also in which way do I use regularization after?

Can someone helo me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you read something about finding a good architecture for a network, which typically goes like this: build network that is "too big" (i.e. too many layers), then remove layers until performance starts dropping. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Probably yes. I don't have really a guide on how to do this, but every time this was written just in few lines, and never found a full argumentation. Removing number of layers seems a good solution, but also to make the network overfit I should not use any regularization, and then when overfitted I could add for example dropout to reduce the overfitting. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of overfitting is generally because of the high(unnecessary) complexity model. So if you train a too complex(large) model, you will get a high training accuracy and low test set accuracy. Then you can start to fight with overfitting  with `getting more data`, `dropout`, `regularization`, `early stopping`, `global average pooling`, `feature scale clipping` or `dropping some of layers from your network`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are talking about `orthogonalization`, in this approach you break the focus of model fitting into 4 stages:

You build a model that:

Step 1: Fits the training data well, this is the primary focus at this point, in this step overfitting is likely to occur.

Step 2: Fits dev data well, in this step you likely to add regularization to address overfitting

Step 3: Fits test data well, this step is needed because dev data has been heavily experimented against and the model could overfit to the dev data.

Step 4: Fits real world data well